# mvc 4 how to capture when a user logs in?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating an application using MVC4.  I am trying to work out how to capture when a user logs in.

I thought I could add some code in the login Action in Account controller..

```
  public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid &&  _authProvider.Login(model.UserName, model.Password,  true))
            {
                var currentUser = Membership.GetUser();

                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }
```

but the currentUser is always null? why is that?  How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Hard to say.. what is _authProvider?  That's not anything that MVC provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Membership.GetUser()` doesn't work because it uses the `HttpContext.Current.Identity` to retrieve the the user, but this will not get set until the next page refresh.

The reason is that your Login method most likely uses `FormsAuthentication.SetCookie()` (or some variation) to create an auth ticket, but that ticket has to be read on a page load to be valid.  Since the current page is already loaded at this point, authentication is not valid until the next page load.

Regardless, I don't understand why you even need to do this.  You already know the users name.  It's right there, you pass it to the Login method... `model.UserName`.